# How do I get the HREF attribute of an anchor tag?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'm trying to scrape the sites from `http://expo.getbootstrap.com/`

The HTML is like this:

```
<div class="col-span-4">
  <p>
    <a class="thumbnail" target="_blank" href="https://www.getsentry.com/">
      <img src="/screenshots/sentry.jpg">
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
```

My Nokogiri code is:

```
url = "http://expo.getbootstrap.com/"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
puts doc.css("title").text
doc.css(".col-span-4").each do |site|
  title=site.css("h4 a").text
  href = site.css("a.thumbnail")[0]['href']
end
```

The goal is simple, get the `href`, the `<img>` tag's `href`, and the site's `<title>`, but it keeps reporting:

```
undefined method [] for nil:NilClass
```

in the line:

```
href = site.css("a.thumbnail")[0]['href']
```

It really drives me crazy because the code I wrote here is actually working in another situation.

Comment: Whats happening if you try site.css("a.thumbnail")['href'] or site.css("a.thumbnail")['href'][0] ?

Comment: It reports `can't convert String into Integer` in both situations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not accounting for the fact that not all `.col-span-4` divs contain a thumbnail. This should work:

```
url = "http://expo.getbootstrap.com/"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
puts doc.css("title").text
doc.css(".col-span-4").each do |site|
  title = site.css("h4 a").text
  thumbnail = site.css("a.thumbnail")
  next if thumbnail.empty?
  href = thumbnail[0]['href']
end
```

Comment: `next if thumbnail.empty?; href = thumbnail[0]['href']` could be written more succinctly as `href = thumbnail[0]['href'] unless thumbnail.empty?`

Comment: this works! Actually i've consider the situation you stated here. but not write it down above. I use `if title` to decide whether to go for the href. However, the `if title` title is not enought. `if !title.empty?` is the working solution

Answer (score 2):

I'd do something like:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'pp'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://expo.getbootstrap.com/'))

thumbnails = doc.search('a.thumbnail').map{ |thumbnail|
  {
    href: thumbnail['href'],
    src: thumbnail.at('img')['src'],
    title: thumbnail.parent.parent.at('h4 a').text
  }
}

pp thumbnails
```

Which, after running has:

```
# => [
  {
    :href => "https://www.getsentry.com/",
    :src => "/screenshots/sentry.jpg",
    :title => "Sentry"
  },
  {
    :href => "http://laravel.com",
    :src => "/screenshots/laravel.jpg",
    :title => "Laravel"
  },
  {
    :href => "http://gruntjs.com",
    :src => "/screenshots/gruntjs.jpg",
    :title => "Grunt"
  },
  {
    :href => "http://labs.bittorrent.com",
    :src => "/screenshots/bittorrent-labs.jpg",
    :title => "BitTorrent Labs"
  },
  {
    :href => "https://www.easybring.com/en",
    :src => "/screenshots/easybring.jpg",
    :title => "Easybring"
  },
  {
    :href => "http://developers.kippt.com/",
    :src => "/screenshots/kippt-developers.jpg",
    :title => "Kippt Developers"
  },
  {
    :href => "http://www.learndot.com/",
    :src => "/screenshots/learndot.jpg",
    :title => "Learndot"
  },
  {
    :href=>"http://getflywheel.com/",
    :src=>"/screenshots/flywheel.jpg",
    :title=>"Flywheel"
}
]
```